# Compile log does anyone knwo how this error can pop up?

Tags: c++, compilation

i don't know how or why and google wasn't really helpful neighter,,, but can anyone tell why dose this error pops and how may it get fixed? I tried everything i could think of.... i`m out of ideas.

the error part:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project Lab3-5Mod ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               
**** g++ -ID:\c++\Begin\Lab3-5Mod -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o src\UI.o..\src\UI.cpp
 ..\src\UI.cpp: In function 'int printMenu()':
 ..\src\UI.cpp:39:15: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 ..\src\UI.cpp:39:24: error: expected primary-expression before 'int'
 ..\src\UI.cpp:39:39: error: expected primary-expression before 'M'
 ..\src\UI.cpp: In function 'int main()':
 ..\src\UI.cpp:75:18: error: expected primary-expression before 'M'
 Build error occurred, build is stopped
 Time consumed: 370  ms.
```

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Structs.h"
#include "structs.cpp"
#include "controller.cpp"
#include "UI.h"

using namespace std;

int printMenu(){

int input;
input = 1;
    while (input){
        cout<<"1.  Add to current day "<<endl;
        cout<<"2.  Insert amount to day by type "<<endl;
        cout<<"3.  Remove day "<<endl;
        cout<<"4.  Remove days "<<endl;
        cout<<"5.  Remove type of expenses"<<endl;
        cout<<"6.  Replace type  at specified day"<<endl;
        cout<<"7.  Show expenses bigger than"<<endl;
        cout<<"8.  Show expenses bigger than... to day..."<<endl;
        cout<<"9.  Show expenses of specified type overall"<<endl;
        cout<<"10. Calculate sum of specified type over all"<<endl;
        cout<<"11. Show day with highest expenses"<<endl;
        cout<<"12. Show all days with specified expenses"<<endl;
        cout<<"13. Sort days by expenses increasing"<<endl;
        cout<<"14. Sort days by expenses discreasing"<<endl;
        cout<<"15. Filter type"<<endl;
        cout<<"16. Filter type starting with"<<endl;
        cout<<"---------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"18. Undo"<<endl;
        cout<<"0.  Clear and exit!"<<endl;

        cout<<"enter option: ";
        cin>>input;

        switch(input){
        case 1:add(int cant,int tip, Array M);
        case 2:
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 9:
        case 10:
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
        case 14:
        case 15:
        case 16:
        case 17:
        case 18:
        case 19:
        case 0:break;
        default: cout<<"Wrong input!"<<endl;break;

        }
    }

return 0;
}


int main()
{
//Main function of the program. no pre/ post condition.
Array M;
constr(M);
Array B;
constr(B);
dummyData(Array M);

printMenu();
return 0;
}
```

Array header:

```
struct Array{
    int days;
    int exp;
    int **M;
};

void constr(Array &);
void destruc(Array &);
void add(int, int, Array &);
```

Controller add function:

```
void add(int cant,int tip, Array M){
//Adds to current day the amount to a specific type
    currDay();
    M.M[currentDay][tip] += cant;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely not enough info. Please add the declaration of `M` and of `add()`

Comment: These syntax errors are fundamental enough that you need to spend some time doing a C tutorial or reading a book before posting more qs.

Comment: i`m working with a book... but i dont have much time... and i need to for fast and furious and i dont ask how to do something but how to fix errors by that i learn a lot... no need to remember me i donno c++, but stil lthis is a community for asking and respond when you know right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not call functions like that:

```
add(int cant,int tip, Array M);
```

You need not specify the data types:

```
add(cant,tip, M);
```

Also here: `dummyData(Array M);` -> `dummyData(M);`

You specify the data types only in the declaration, but not when calling the functions.

Answer (score 1):

```
    case 1:add(int cant,int tip, Array M);
```

When you call add, you don't specify the types of the actual parameters.